# Build system supports multiple output per target

Tags: build-process

I work in the field of bioinformatics. My daily work processes several data files (DNA sequences, alignments, etc..) and produce many result files, so I want to use something like Unix make to automate the whole process, especially to resolve dependencies between different data.

However, the Unix make only supports one output per target, as it is designed for software build, which typically generates one object file from several source files, or one executable from several object files. If you use custom virtual targets, it won't benefit from timestamp checking. Is there any build system that supports multiple output file per one target? If there aren't any, I'm going to make the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Drake](https://github.com/Factual/drake), which is a replacement of make designed for data workflow management (make for data).

Another option is [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net), which is an improved make. Among other features it supports multiple targets.